# Windows/CLI | Search in file for specific string/value and set it to variable

Tags: windows, search, cmd, windows-10, command-line-interface

Lets say I have a names.txt file or names.xml or names.html. And it contains something like this:

```
<name>John</name><age>21</age>
```

Now if I run `findstr "name" names.txt` it outputs the whole line with all the text in it, including age.

How do I output only `John` because it's inside `<name></name>` and I searched for `name` and set `John` to a variable?

3rd-party CLI solutions are welcome.

Comment: PowerShell supports [`-match`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) with proper tokens and delimiters. Consider: `batch` is not the best solution for parsing XML.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,5 delims=<>" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set name=%%a
  set age=%%b
)
echo %name%, %age%
```

Comment: what does 2,5 stand for